# Where does finger info come from in RedHat?

Tags: linux, redhat

One of the data elements produced by the `finger` command gives information on how long a logged in session has been idle.  Where does finger get that information from on RedHat?  I've looked in `/proc/<pid>/` but did not find anything useful, and the documentation doesn't go into the commands implementation.

So, where in the system is finger (or w) pulling this information from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finger` program get's this information from [utmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) file located at `/var/run/utmp`.

Comment: sorry, but the data is not there.  unfortunately with the question closed I don't know where I will find the answer.

Comment: What do you mean "the data is not there"? How did you check it? How did you detect it? Most probably I will disagree: No, "redhat" being a posix system, the data "is there".

Comment: there is no 'utmp' entry in /var/log

Comment: maybe /var/run/utmp? Right, it's a  typo, it's /var/run/utmp. It's in the documentation I linked under section "FILES"... wtmp is in /var/log.

Comment: Thank you, KamilCuk!  Now I can look into the format of that file - just needed to know what was being used.

Comment: just an update - following the chain from utmp, w, etc... I was able to look at some code to see that /dev/pts/<device> is what is being used for idle time.  Just stating that gets me the info I need.  Thanks again!